# Is there a free image editor software to handle grid image

Tags: css

In order to load image quickly in webpage, we merger many small images into a big image and use the following css to show certain small image.

Is there a free image editor software to add, edit or delete a small image in big image?

Thanks!

```
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul { border: solid 1px #ccc; margin: 1px; padding: 1px; float: left; background: #fff url(jHtmlArea_Toolbar_Group_BG.png) repeat-x;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h1 { background-position: 0 -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h2 { background-position: -16px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h3 { background-position: -32px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h4 { background-position: -48px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h5 { background-position: -64px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h6 { background-position: -80px -16px;}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's called sprites, the technique to add many images into one.
This looks like a good tool: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Comment: Why are there 3 aswers that talk about sprites? Combining small images into one large image has nothing to do with sprites. Sprites are those small images that move on top of the background in games.

Comment: And they've taken the same name for this technique in web design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you mean [Sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS).

I've heard recommendations for [SpriteCow](http://www.spritecow.com) - and [here](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/105-using-spritecow/)'s a video on one CSS pro using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Compass Sprites](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/), it's easy and autogenerate sprite image and CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think any image editor can be used to combine small images into a large image. Even Windows Paint can do that.

1. Open two instances of Paint, one for the combined image and one to load the small images.
2. Open a small image into Paint #1. Copy it (or part of it) to clipboard.
3. Switch to Paint #2 and paste the image from clipboard. You can then move the pasted image to any position inside the big image.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 for each small image you want to add.